# How to open a url in new tab?

Tags: javascript

I have used to work with attribute:

```
target='_blank' <!-- in HTML -->
```

But with JavaScript i have tried:

```
windows.open('my_url' [, args]);
```

I want to open `my_url` in another TAB but the problem with this function is it opens the url in a new window

I have tried also to add argument to the function like `'_blank'` or `'_newtab'` but not working.
Is there any solution to open url in new tab and not in a new window ?

Comment: You can't specify where exactly the window should be opened to. That's up to the browser. That said, I know for a fact that IE has a "When a popup is encountered" setting with "always open in a new tab" as an option.

Comment: If you have element which opens a link in new tab then simulate a click event on that element on any event.

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window but you try this trick

```
function OpenInNewTab(url )
{
  var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

<div onclick="OpenInNewTab();">Something To Click On</div>
```

reference: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: vote down for answer a marked as duplicate question?